# TypeScript const and knockout pureComputed

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I have a **compilation** problem referencing `this` object in function `problem`:

```
const c = {
  f() {
    console.log("hi");
  },

  problem: ko.pureComputed(() => {
    return this.f();
  }),
};
```

*[ts] The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this' which implicitly has type 'any'.*

If I reference `this` as `c`:

```
const c = {
  f() {
    console.log("hi");
  },

  problem: ko.pureComputed(() => {
    return c.f();
  }),
};
```

*[ts] 'c' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.*

Can anybody help, please? and possibly explain? Thanx.

Comment: Could you clarify a little more what the problem is? I'm not sure what output you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I extracted this piece from real application to demonstrate compiler error I can't resolve. I simply want to reference "current object" in function `problem` but whether I address it as `this` or as `c`, compiler is not satisfied. Output is not relevant here, only how to tell compiler my intent.

Comment: Have you tried to do smth like `class C { code here }` instead of `const c = ...`?

Comment: @ingvar OK that works, thanks. But is that only way? I mean - when I need to some single object with some encapsulated properties and methods, I need to define class and create singleton? That overhead seems more like Java, not like JavaScript at all. But whatever, thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with TS, but AFAIK TS requires strict types everywhere, it doesn't allow to use objects created via literal or somehow else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @ingvar's comment I found acceptable solution using anonymous class:

```
const c = new class {
  f() {
    console.log("hi");
  }

  problem = ko.pureComputed(() => {
    return this.f();
  }, this);
}();
```

Compilation is successful now, it is syntactically short and semantically correct.